# \glsentryfull with link

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{T}{T}{Test}

\begin{document}
    \gls{T}

    \gls{T}

    \glsentryfull{T}
\end{document}
```

Which gives the following output:

[image]

In my actual text, a government agency is mentioned early in the text (so its name and acronym are shown), but then I later have a description of various agencies, and want that agency's name and acronym to appear again, even though the acronym has already been defined. So I've used `\glsentryfull{}`. However, I'd like this to be hyperref'ed as well.

Is there a way to make `\glsentryfull{T}` also generate a link, preferably so as to look identical to the first `\gls`? Use of `glossaries-extra` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just the base `glossaries` package use `\acrfull`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{T}{T}{Test}

\begin{document}
    \gls{T}

    \gls{T}

    \acrfull{T}
\end{document}
```

[image: Test (T) T Test (T)]

Note there's a minor difference if you use `\setacronymstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{T}{T}{Test}

\begin{document}
    \gls{T}

    \gls{T}

    \acrfull{T}
\end{document}
```

[image: Test (T) T Test (T)]

In the first case `\acrfull` has two hyperlinks and in the second it only has one.

With `glossaries-extra` use `\glsxtrfull`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\newacronym{T}{T}{Test}

\begin{document}
    \gls{T}

    \gls{T}

    \glsxtrfull{T}
\end{document}
```

This has the same result as the second case.

[image: Test (T) T Test (T)]